# Using a custom generator vs Arbitrary instance in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Here's a simple function.  It takes an input `Int` and returns a (possibly empty) list of `(Int, Int)` pairs, where the input `Int` is the sum of the cubed elements of any of the pairs.

```
cubeDecomposition :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
cubeDecomposition n = [(x, y) | x <- [1..m], y <- [x..m], x^3 + y^3 == n] 
  where m = truncate $ fromIntegral n ** (1/3)

-- cubeDecomposition 1729
-- [(1,12),(9,10)]
```

I want to test the property that the above is true; if I cube each element and sum any of the return tuples, then I get my input back:

```
import Control.Arrow 

cubedElementsSumToN :: Int -> Bool
cubedElementsSumToN n = all (== n) d
    where d = map (uncurry (+) . ((^3) *** (^3))) (cubeDecomposition n)
```

For runtime considerations, I'd like to limit the input `Int`s to a certain size when testing this with QuickCheck.  I can define an appropriate type and `Arbitrary` instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Test.QuickCheck

newtype SmallInt = SmallInt Int
    deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Ord, Num, Real, Integral)

instance Arbitrary SmallInt where
    arbitrary = fmap SmallInt (choose (-10000000, 10000000))
```

And then I guess I have to define versions of the function and property that use `SmallInt` rather than `Int`:

```
cubeDecompositionQC :: SmallInt -> [(SmallInt, SmallInt)]
cubeDecompositionQC n = [(x, y) | x <- [1..m], y <- [x..m], x^3 + y^3 == n] 
  where m = truncate $ fromIntegral n ** (1/3)

cubedElementsSumToN' :: SmallInt -> Bool
cubedElementsSumToN' n = all (== n) d
    where d = map (uncurry (+) . ((^3) *** (^3))) (cubeDecompositionQC n)

-- cubeDecompositionQC 1729
-- [(SmallInt 1,SmallInt 12),(SmallInt 9,SmallInt 10)]
```

This works fine, and the standard 100 tests pass as expected.  But it seems unnecessary to define a new type, instance, and function when all I really need is a custom generator.  So I tried this:

```
smallInts :: Gen Int
smallInts = choose (-10000000, 10000000)

cubedElementsSumToN'' :: Int -> Property
cubedElementsSumToN'' n = forAll smallInts $ \m -> all (== n) (d m)
    where d =   map (uncurry (+) . ((^3) *** (^3)))
              . cubeDecomposition
```

Now, the first few times I ran this, everything worked fine, and all tests pass.  But on subsequent runs I observed failures.  Bumping up the test size reliably finds one:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 674 tests and 1 shrink):  
0
8205379
```

I'm a bit confused here due to the presence of *two* shrunken inputs - 0 and 8205379 - returned from QuickCheck, where I would intuitively expect one.  Also, those inputs work as predicted (on my show-able property, at least):

```
*Main> cubedElementsSumToN 0
True
*Main> cubedElementsSumToN 8205379
True
```

So it seems like obviously there's a problem in the property that uses the custom `Gen` I defined.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: It seems obvious to me now that there's no reason `n` and `m` should be equal, as I've required them to be in `cubedElementsSumToN''`.  So, the property is turning out `False` whenever it's fed an element that yields a nonempty list.  I'll probably answer this myself in a few minutes.

Comment: You don't need new versions of your functions to use with the `newtype` wrapper. Instead, just pattern match on it to get at the underlying `Int`. For example, you can write `cubedElementsSumToN' (SmallInt n) = ...` instead of using `forAll`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quickly realized that the property as I've written it is obviously incorrect.  Here's the proper way to do it, using the original `cubedElementsSumToN` property:

```
quickCheck (forAll smallInts cubedElementsSumToN)
```

which reads quite naturally.